# No module named urls.py

Tags: django

I've been following the django tutorial over at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/ but I've hit a brick wall.

*yes* I have searched google and looked up the 15 or so exact questions and nothing is working.

My directory structure is:

```
djangotest/
  urls.py
  settings.py
```

My settings has this

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls.py'
```

The generator generated urls.py, not djangotest.urls as detailed in the tutorial. However, I don't think the naming matters too much. I've tried every variation of this urls file and I am having errors spat at me every time. The main one being the above.

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^reviews/$', 'djangotest.review.urls')
)
```

I'd love some help with this like how I can debug?

Comment: Python uses directories to package code, and files represent modules, so djangotest.urls means "the urls.py file in the djangotest directory."

Comment: I see. Thanks very much. I'll study more!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you being careful about the projectname and appname?  Are you following the right tutorial for the version of django you downloaded?  I'd also recommend using the latest stable release http://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.3.1/tarball/ rather than the latest dev release.

I'd recommend starting over; because without posting all your files (or steps you did), we aren't going to be able to debug where you went wrong.

Also, it seems like just running:

```
django-admin.py startproject my_test_project
cd my_test_project
django-admin.py startapp my_test_app
```

that you should have a directory structure like:

```
my_test_project/
|-- __init__.py
|-- manage.py
|-- my_test_app
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- tests.py
|   `-- views.py
|-- settings.py
`-- urls.py
```

`settings.py` should have `ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_test_project.urls'`, which reads the data in `urls.py` with no errors if you try

```
./manage runserver
```

and point your web browser to http://127.0.0.1:8000

---

On your update, it seems your specific mistake seems to be that your urls.py references `'djangotest.review.urls'`  Is there an app (in the installed apps) named review in the project `djangotest` with a `urls.py`?  Are all the permissions correct?

Comment: It was because urls.py should have been djangotest.urls - I didn't realize about the module.file naming convention. Thanks for the thought out answer! I think you're right, I should probably start again and use the latest stable release.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to have a file named "`__init__.py`" in each directory where you have .py files. These indicate to python that the directory is a python package. Also, verify the ownership and permissions on the files/folder to make sure you can access them as the user running the server.

Comment: As an aside, they also need to be in your python path.